# how to change files into folders (Windows 10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-attributes

I was using autoit to rename folders, and I used FileMove instead of DirMove. It did move all the data from the folder, but wrote the destination folder as a FILE - Without the D attribute - so windows treats it as a FILE. I have good reason to believe that the data inside hasn't changed, It's just missing the D Attribute.

Is there any tool or method to set the D attribute of a file on windows? I've been googling for 2 hours and have had no luck.

Comment: Have you tried "extracting" the file using 7zip?

Comment: 7zip doesn't recognize it as an archive. Had that thought too

Maybe if I put it INTO a .zip file, I could do some hex editor fuckery on the archive, and then extract the folder. I have no clue how i'd do that.

Comment: If you move a folder to a single file target, it normally gets overwritten, doesn't the size of the file give you a hint of the actual content?